# git commit --amend opens Vim in terminal

Tags: git, github, sublimetext

Whenever I use **git commit --amend**, it automatically opens **Vim** on **Terminal**. Since I am a **Sublime Text 2** user, I would love to have this editor opening whenever I execute this command.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set Sublime Text 2 to be your editor for commits

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

But I do not use Sublime, so check this :
https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/

Comment: As the link mentions you have to make sure to set up the `subl` command. You can do so by following [these instructions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html)

Comment: for OSX and Sublime 3, it worked after doing this: https://gist.github.com/martinbuberl/5823ed247d279d1a2d06